Global Temp tables created in Sequence Container don't persist
I'm moving data from a server that I have limited permissions on so I'm stuck with ##Temp tables or one giant script to process data before writing it to our main server. Processing the data requires 10 different queries. I can run five of them at the same time so I put them in a Sequence Container. All five of them create ##Temps which are later used in the main query. However...none of them are visible after they complete. If I take them all out of the container and run them in sequence one at a time...they all persist. So it's the Sequence Container somehow causing the global temp tables to delete immediately after I'm done filling them.
I 100% have RetainSameConnection = True in my ConnectionManager.
ChatG suggested maybe setting IsolationLevl = ReadUncommitted...did not help.
I don't have to put them in a sequence container but it would be more efficient if I could.  Both SQL and Visual Studio are 2019.  Any ideas?

When you say none are available after created, how are you determing that? If you add a breakpoint after the sequence container that creates them, leave that active and go query the global temporary table - does it exist?

Global ##temp tables disappear when the last (often only) connection referencing them disconnects. Why not use permanent tables? If two instances of the processes can run concurrently, that's a problem anyway (since they'll be inadvertently sharing the table). If they can't, then a permanent table is the same as a global ##temp table, except it doesn't disappear.

I have put Breakpoints on the Post Execute event of one or more of the steps in the container and then in SSMS SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ##Temp1 etc.  SQL Comlains they don't exist and then the next step that combines them also fails.

I'm on Government servers.  I have full permissions on the destination server but limited on the source.  It would take sooo much red tape to even request create permissions and we probably wouldn't get them.  So kind of stuck with ##Temp or transfer all source data and then process...talking millions or rows.

You can't CREATE TABLE dbo.TableName in tempdb? At least that would only disappear if the server restarted.

RetainSameConnection won't help if you have multiple operations that need to access the Connection Manager at the same time.
You could create the tables in an initial script task and save the open connection to a package variable.  This should keep those global temp tables alive for all the connections opened by the Connection Manger.
So

create a package variable called "SqlConnection"
create a Script Task in your control flow with read/write access to that variable

Open a SqlConnection and create the global temp tables in the script task, eg:

        /// </summary>
        public void Main()
        {

            var con = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=master;Integrated Security=true");
            con.Open();
            var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "Create table ##foo(id int, msg varchar(2000))";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Dts.Variables["User::SqlConnection"].Value = con;

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }


Add another script task to close the connection
Put your sequence container between the two script tasks, and all the tasks in the sequence container will have access to the global temp tables.



That would explain the behavior.  Thank you!  I'll look into this and get back to you.

I spend the majority of my time writint SQL scripts in MS SQL and Databricks.  Once in a while I create fairly simple SSIS packages using Execute SQL tasks to automate some of the MS SQL stuff.  On rare occasions I use data flow objects for cross server transfer.
With that said...I could use a little extra help understanding your solution?  Create tables outside of the Sequence Container and then just do an INSERT in the container?  Or are you saying use something like C# to open a connection and track it's state using a boolean variable?

Ok...you were suggesting the more complicated version.  While waiting I went ahead and  manually created my five ##Temp tables in a Execute SQL task just before the Sequence Container and then used INSERT INTO SELECT vs SELECT INTO FROM.  All tables persisted through the container and everything is working.

David Browne from Microsoft inspired a solution.  His response was a bit above my pay grade so I asked for further assistance.  While waiting for his clarification I tried something I though he might have meant and IT WORKED.
His explination makes sense and explains the behavior.  If multiple tables are created at the same time under one connection manager (like in a Sequence Container creating five ##Temp tables) then they will not persist.
So...just manually create them in an "Execute SQL" object before the Sequence Container and fill then using a INSERT INTO SELECT inside the container...
If for some reason this doesn't work...explore the more complicated answer that requires using C# to create connections and managing them trhoughtout the package.  Make sure you have error catching code to close them in the even of an error...don't want leaks.
Thank you so much David Browne for the assist...I was lost on this one!

It's always the little things!
